# Idling and ExternalEvent are not raised while an Element is selected

Tags: c#, wpf, revit-api

I'm building a Revit AddIn with WPF modeless dialogs and I want to use an ExternalEvent to retrieve Elements selected by the user. Is what I am doing viable and what do I need to change for it to work?

Since I don't have a valid API document context, I raise an ExternalEvent when a button is clicked to retrieve UniqueId of Elements that are currently selected.

Here are the relevant classes (I tried to reduce the code as much as I could) :

```cs
public class App : IExternalApplication {
  internal static App _app = null;
  public static App Instance => _app;

  public Result OnStartup(UIControlledApplication application) {
    _app = this;
    return Result.Succeeded;
  }

  public void ShowWin(UIApplication ui_app) {
    var eventHandler = new CustomEventHandler();
    var externalEvent = ExternalEvent.Create(eventHandler);
    var window = new WPFWindow(eventHandler, externalEvent);
    Process proc = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
    WindowInteropHelper helper = new WindowInteropHelper(window) {
      Owner = proc.MainWindowHandle
    };
    window.Show();
  }
}

public class AddIn : IExternalCommand {
  public Result Execute(ExternalCommandData commandData, ref string message, ElementSet elements) {
    App.Instance.ShowWin(commandData.Application);
    return Result.Succeeded;
  }
}

public class CustomEventHandler : IExternalEventHandler {
  public event Action<List<string>> CustomEventHandlerDone;

  public void Execute(UIApplication ui_app) {
    UIDocument ui_doc = ui_app.ActiveUIDocument;
    if (ui_doc == null) {
      return;
    }
    Document doc = ui_doc.Document;
    List<string> element_ids = null;
    var ui_view = ui_doc.GetOpenUIViews().Where(x => x.ViewId == doc.ActiveView.Id).FirstOrDefault();
    if (doc.ActiveView is View3D view3d && ui_view != null) {
      using (Transaction tx = new Transaction(doc)) {
        tx.Start();
        element_ids = ui_doc.Selection.GetElementIds().Select(x => doc.GetElement(x)?.UniqueId).Where(x => x != null).ToList();
        tx.Commit();
      }
    }
    this.CustomEventHandlerDone?.Invoke(element_ids);
  }
}

public partial class WPFWindow {
  private CustomEventHandler _eventHandler;
  private ExternalEvent _externalEvent;

  public WPFWindow(CustomEventHandler eventHandler, ExternalEvent externalEvent) {
    this._eventHandler = eventHandler;
    this._eventHandler.CustomEventHandlerDone += this.WPFWindow_CustomEventDone;
    this._externalEvent = externalEvent;
  }

  private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    this._externalEvent.Raise();
  }

  private void WPFWindow_CustomEventDone(List<string> element_ids) {
    // this point is never reached while an element is selected
  }
}
```

When an element is selected, the ExternalEvent is marked as pending but is only executed when the selection is cleared by the user.

The same happens with `UIControlledApplication.Idling`.

I would like for it to be executed even when elements are selected, or an alternative way to do it, and not involving PickObject.

Comment: Are you really saying that when the set of currently selected and highlighted elements elements in Revit is non-empty, the Idling event is never fired?

Comment: I have to correct myself in that regard. It is not never fired. However, there are configurations where the event is "constantly not fired". It seems it has to do with which elements are selected. If I take the example of the "rac_basic_sample_project.rvt" file, when my WPF window is on the screen, Idling event is not fired while selecting the roof (ID 243274).

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem.

I was able to determine that the problem occurs if elements of the same family are selected. Moreover, there is a certain threshold value, somewhere from 10 to 20 or more, at which this is manifested.

I was able to get around this by canceling the selection of elements `UIDocument.Selection.SetElementIds(new List<ElementId>())` before calling `ExternalEvent.Raise()`. And then at the end return the selection, if necessary.

Comment: I had completely different use case but I can confirm that at certain point calling Raise wont result in executing the external event handler, regardless the fact it make zero sense, after clearing the selection before calling raise it seems problem disappeared